# How to Find any random value in address bar , When we Redirect to Error page

Tags: asp.net

We have set the error page in our Application. When we type any string without .aspx extension its redirect to Error page Like:
http://www.demo.com/typeany when we enter any random value its Redirect to Error Page
and in Error Page (http://www.demo.com/typeany) url showing in address bar.
Now I want to fetch typeany string in Error page.
I was tried to fetch, but current url showing(Error.aspx), Failed to fetch random value.

Thanks:

Comment: Have you tried query string? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> string apppath = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.RawUrl);
>
> string dummypath = apppath.Replace("/ErrorPage.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/", "");